# Problems importing functions with @importFrom pkg fun

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to develop my first R package and run into a following problem.

I have a DESCRIPTION file where all needed packages are listed under *Imports* like suggested by Hadley Wickham in his book. I'm using `@importFrom dplyr select` to load a function, for internal use.

By running `devtools::document()` I get an error:

> Error in select(paths_original, household_id = H_ID, person_id = P_ID,  : 
>     could not find function "select"

Would be great, if someone could help me to understand my mistake.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: first_package
Title: first package
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Description: first package
Depends:
    R (>= 3.5.2)
Imports:
    foreign (>= 0.8.71),
    plyr (>= 1.8.4),
    dplyr (>= 0.7.7),
    leaflet (>= 2.0.2),
    sf (>= 0.7.1),
    rgeos (>= 0.4.2),
    geosphere (>= 1.5.7),
    sp (>= 1.3.1),
    rgdal (>= 1.3.6),
    mapview (>= 2.6.0),
    lwgeom (>= 0.1.6),
    roxygen2
License: BSD 2-Clause + file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.0
```

function:

```
get_clear_df_paths <- function(paths_original) {
  clean_paths <- select(paths_original,
                        household_id = H_ID,
                        person_id = P_ID,
                        household_person_id = HP_ID,
                        weekday = ST_WOTAG,
                        month = ST_MONAT,
                        holiday = feiertag,
                        season = saison,
                        regular_job_related_path = W_RBW,
                        path_purpose = W_ZWECK,
                        starting_point = W_SO2,
                        start_time_hour = W_SZS,
                        start_time_min = W_SZM,
                        arrival_next_day = W_FOLGETAG,
                        arrival_time_hour = W_AZS,
                        arrival_time_min = W_AZM,
                        path_length = wegkm,
                        path_length_imp = wegkm_imp,
                        path_duration_min = wegmin,
                        path_duration_min_imp = wegmin_imp,
                        main_vehicle = hvm,
                        car_driver = pkw_fmf,
                        vehicle_car = W_VM_G,
                        vehicle_carsharing = W_VM_H,
                        district = stt_mun)
}
```

imports.R

```
#' @importFrom plyr revalue
#' @importFrom dplyr select
#' @importFrom foreign read.spss
NULL
```

NAMESPACE

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

importFrom(dplyr,select)
importFrom(foreign,read.spss)
importFrom(plyr,revalue)
```

public gist link with relevant code snippets:

https://gist.github.com/bgrt/b7d32cb3aa0bb128f276bad86c89bdd4

Comment: Why not just use `dplyr::select`?

Comment: Ok, you're right, it would be possible just to use `dplyr::select`, but I have a lot of functions I'm using from the dplyr package, so the recommended way is to use the `@importFrom` statement. And of course I would like to understand where my mistake is

Comment: Could you copy paste your code and add it to the question? Also add a GitHub or other link to the function?

Comment: @NelsonGon's latest comment it dead on: This is not reproducible as is. We cannot tell you where your problem is if we cannot see your code.

Comment: by the way `@importFrom foreign read.spss` works fine in contrast to `select` and `revalue`

Comment: Try this `importFrom(dplyr,"select")` in your NAMESPACE file. Although it should really make no difference.

Comment: This seems... bizarre. I have an easily mocked up minimal example showing that this approach **should** work. I have to imagine there's some outside factor we're not seeing. What versions of R, devtools, roxygen2, and dplyr do you have?

Comment: added the DESCRIPTION file to the post

roxygen2 - 6.1.0
devtools - 2.0.1
dplyr - 0.7.7
R - 3.5.2

Comment: Could you try to also update to `roxygen2` 6.1.1 or higher?

Comment: updated: doesn't solve the error. just changes the `RoxygenNote` at the bottom of the DESCRIPTION file to 6.1.1

Comment: I would advise to host the function as is and post the link here. It is currently difficult to know why it doesn't work.  Specifically, it would be great to see what the documentation looks like above the function. You also need `@export`. @Bagrat

Comment: I added the gist link to the OP... I yet don't have any documentation for the functions. but at this point, seems to me its kind of irrelevant, because I think I'm missing something R relevant, because I'm new to the language and package development...

Comment: It's not irrelevant because only exported functions can be used and `document`ation should use this info. I would put `@importFrom pkg function` above my function before `export`ing it.

Comment: I'm using the source statement in my execute_preprocessing.R file ... I know I should avoid this and instead put `@export` statements above the functions to use them. I used the source statements because I didn't planned to develop a package. At some point I decided to reorganize everything and create the package. 

long story short: `@export` statement above the `get_clear_df_paths` function doesnt solve the error...

Answer (score 1):

I hate to add this because it is "Not an answer," and will update it to include an answer soon or remove it. However, I believe it may be helpful to demonstrate that OP's basic approach **should** work, so I created a minimal example package importing the apparent problem function.

First I set up the package structure:

```r
library(devtools)
create_package("funImport", rstudio = FALSE)
use_package("dplyr")
use_gpl3_license("X")
```

I then added one file to `R/` containing the following:

```r
#' Select wrapper
#' 
#' @param .data A tbl
#' @param ... Variable names to select
#' 
#' @return The selected variables
#' @export
Select <- function(.data, ...) {
    return(select(.data, ...))
}

#' @importFrom dplyr select
NULL
```

I was then able to `document()`, `install()` and `check()` no problem:

```r
document()
# Updating funImport documentation
# Updating roxygen version in /home/jb/funImport/DESCRIPTION
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Loading funImport
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Writing Select.Rd
install()
# Output omitted
check()
# Some output omitted
# ── R CMD check results ─────────────────────────────── funImport 0.0.0.9000 ────
# Duration: 48.2s
# 
# 0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

I was also able to use the function no problem:

```r
library(funImport)
tbl <- tibble::tibble(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])
tbl
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#        x y    
#    <int> <chr>
#  1     1 a    
#  2     2 b    
#  3     3 c    
#  4     4 d    
#  5     5 e    
#  6     6 f    
#  7     7 g    
#  8     8 h    
#  9     9 i    
# 10    10 j  
Select(tbl, x)
# # A tibble: 10 x 1
#        x
#    <int>
#  1     1
#  2     2
#  3     3
#  4     4
#  5     5
#  6     6
#  7     7
#  8     8
#  9     9
# 10    10
```

Comment: `use_x` seem to have been moved to `usethis`.

Comment: @NelsonGon Sure, but if you attach `devtools`, it also attached `usethis`

Comment: @NelsonGon See here: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/blob/5a973d6af532a96f37e4f2714791c0a68e6d2a8a/R/zzz.R#L68

Answer (score 1):

Created a dummy package to test and this works. You need to have your functions documented as shown below. Also, please have a way fo providing global binding for some variables in your functions.

```
    #' Some paths
    #' @description some paths
    #' @param paths_original Some path
    #' @importFrom dplyr select
    #' @export 
    get_clear_df_paths <- function(paths_original) {
      clean_paths <- select(paths_original,
                            household_id = H_ID,
                            person_id = P_ID,
                            household_person_id = HP_ID,
                            weekday = ST_WOTAG,
                            month = ST_MONAT,
                            holiday = feiertag,
                            season = saison,
                            regular_job_related_path = W_RBW,
                            path_purpose = W_ZWECK,
                            starting_point = W_SO2,
                            start_time_hour = W_SZS,
                            start_time_min = W_SZM,
                            arrival_next_day = W_FOLGETAG,
                            arrival_time_hour = W_AZS,
                            arrival_time_min = W_AZM,
                            path_length = wegkm,
                            path_length_imp = wegkm_imp,
                            path_duration_min = wegmin,
                            path_duration_min_imp = wegmin_imp,
                            main_vehicle = hvm,
                            car_driver = pkw_fmf,
                            vehicle_car = W_VM_G,
                                vehicle_carsharing = W_VM_H,
                                district = stt_mun)
    }
```

Steps:

```
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)
create("SODummypkg")
document("SODummypkg")
check("SODummypkg")
```

Outcome: Ignore the warning(for purposes of this answer). At least the error doesn't show up.

```
-- R CMD check results ---------------------------------------------- SODummypkg 0.0.0.9000 ----
Duration: 1m 10.7s

> checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
  Dependence on R version '3.5.3' not with patchlevel 0

0 errors √ | 1 warning x | 0 notes √
```

Comment: not sure how to use this to solve my problem... sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @Bagrat Try to document one of your functions as shown here. Also document all your functions.